# M-step of the EM algorithm for finding the ML estimate of θ

Tags: inference, expectation-maximization

Can someone explain to me the procedure of computing the M step of the EM algorithm for a distribution that belongs to a regular exponential family? If I had a set of steps to follow I think I would understand it better.

Comment: Have you done minimal research at least in this site? I am sure there would be many helpful posts on this.

Comment: I did actually, but I’m still lost. If there’s any you’ve found that could be useful please share!

Comment: This is explained in so many places that a simple google search should give you what you look for. For instance, I immediately found: https://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ml1-2018/lect3-handout.pdf which seems to explain it (slide 6 of 8). By using google, you may be able to find many more similar useful websites.